# How can I check if an SD card is present in an Android device?

Tags: android

How can I check if an SD card is present in an Android device? I'm especially interested in solutions for Android 2.2 and 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the external storage is avilable, but you do not know, if this is an SD-Card or not. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: Hi i want to decide this.

Comment: I had one app, where I wanted to do this as well, but there seems to be no way.